# Possible (Minor) Error in Original Lieb-Robinson Bound Paper

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, causality, spin-models

## Introduction

I was reading through [Lieb and Robinson's original paper](http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/talks/CMTjournalclub/sources/LR.pdf) introducing their eponymous bounds, and I came upon the following statement:

> The task remains of corroborating our assertions concerning the Green's functions. These functions can be explicitly calculated in matrix
> form and one finds : \begin{equation*}\mathbf{G}(x, t) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^\nu}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta_1 \cdots\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta_\nu e^{i\theta.x}\exp\{t\omega(\theta)\mathbf{D}\}\end{equation*}
> where where $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{G}$ are matrices whose $(i,j)$ elements are respectively $d_{i,j}$ and
> $G_j^i(x,t)$ and
> $$\omega(\theta)= \sum_{\mathbf{y}\in R^\Phi} e^{+i\theta.y}.$$

After going through and attempting to verify this, I've become convinced that this is slightly incorrect, and in fact, $\omega(\theta)$ should be $\sum_{\mathbf{y}\in R^\Phi} e^{-i\theta.y},$ and $\mathbf{D}$ should be transposed in the above integral. In the rest of this question I will explain my reasoning for such a conclusion. My question is simple: is this reasoning correct? Is what the paper states in fact erroneous? It is worth noting that either way, nothing really changes in the remainder of the paper, as one need only replace $\theta+i\gamma$ with $\theta-i\gamma$ in page 256 of the paper and the argument follows.

## Reasoning

$G^i_j(x,t)$ is defined in the paper in the following way:

> Next, consider the Green's function $G^k_i(x, t)$ defined by the differential equations
> \begin{equation*}\frac{\partial G^k_i(x,t)}{\partial t}=(\overline{\mathscr{L}}G^k)_i(x,t)\end{equation*}
> and
> \begin{equation*}G_j^k(x,0)=\delta_{x,0}\delta_{j,k}\end{equation*}
> $(\overline{\mathscr{L}}$ is the adjoint of $\mathscr{L})$.

Well this in turn requires us to know the definition of $\mathscr{L}$ in order to take its adjoint. That definition is given as
\begin{equation*} (\mathscr{L}F)_i(x,t)=\sum_{y\in R^\Phi}\sum_{j=1}^{N^2}d_{ji}(\Phi)F_j(x+y,t).\end{equation*} The first difficulty in finding the adjoint is that the paper does not tell us what inner product the adjoint should be calculated with, but the most natural one seems to me to be
\begin{equation*} (a_i(x,t), b_i(x,t))\to \sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}^\nu}\sum_{i=1}^{N^2} a_i(x,t)b_i(x,t),\end{equation*} as $\mathscr{L}$ likewise leaves the $t$ argument alone.

If this is indeed the adjoint, then it was straightforward for me to show that

\begin{align*}(\overline{\mathscr{L} }V)_i(x,t) = \sum_{y\in R^\Phi}\sum_{j=1}^{N^2} d_{ij}V_j(x-y,t).\end{align*}

However, when we take the derivative of the integral expression of $\mathbf{G}(x,t)$ as described above, we have that
\begin{align*} \frac{\partial \mathbf{G}(x,t)}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{1}{(2\pi)^\nu}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta_1 \cdots\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta_\nu e^{i\theta.x}\exp\{t\omega(\theta)\mathbf{D}\}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^\nu}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta_1 \cdots\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta_\nu e^{i\theta.x}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\exp\{t\omega(\theta)\mathbf{D}\}\\
&= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^\nu}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta_1 \cdots\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta_\nu e^{i\theta.x}\omega(\theta)\mathbf{D}\exp\{t\omega(\theta)\mathbf{D}\}\\
&= \sum_{y\in R^\phi} \mathbf{D} \left(\frac{1}{(2\pi)^\nu}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta_1 \cdots\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta_\nu e^{i\theta.(x+y)}\exp\{t\omega(\theta)\mathbf{D}\}\right)\\
&= \sum_{y\in R^\Phi}  \mathbf{D}\mathbf{G}(x+y,t)=\sum_{y\in R^\Phi}  \mathbf{G}(x+y,t)\mathbf{D},\end{align*} where I used that a matrix always commutes with its exponential to get the last equality.

Were $\omega(\theta)=\sum_{y\in R^\Phi}e^{-i\theta.y},$ we would get $ \sum_{y\in R^\Phi}  \mathbf{G}(x-y,t)\mathbf{D},$ which, after expanding out the indices suppressed by the matrix notation, gets us
\begin{equation}\frac{\partial G^k_i(x,t)}{\partial t}=\sum_{y\in R^\Phi}\sum_{j=1}^{N^2} G^k_j(x-y,t) d_{ji}=\sum_{y\in R^\Phi}\sum_{j=1}^{N^2} d_{ji}G^k_j(x-y,t). \end{equation} This still isn't quite right, and to fix that, we need $d_{ji}$ to become $d_{ij},$ which sounds like a perfect use case for a transpose. I thus propose the revised form of the Green's functions to be
\begin{equation*}\mathbf{G}(x, t) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^\nu}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta_1 \cdots\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta_\nu e^{i\theta.x}\exp\left\{t\left(\sum_{y\in R^\Phi}e^{-i\theta.y}\right)\mathbf{D}^T\right\}\end{equation*}.

So, is this different form of the Green's function what should have actually been in Lieb and Robinson's paper? If not, why? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you conjugate one side in the inner product?

Comment: I don't think that's necessary because we're only dealing with non-negative $a_i(x,t)$ and $b_i(x,t),$ and the $d_{ij}$ are also always non-negative.

Comment: Hm, but isn't the whole discussion about changing an $i$ to $-i$?

Comment: Yeah, but that comes from $(\overline{\mathscr{L}}V)_i = \sum_{j=1}^{N^2}\sum_{y\in R^\Phi} d_{ij}V_j(x-y,t)$ as opposed to $V_j(x+y,t),$ I think, not due to any conjugate or lack thereof, as the way the $i$s come in is by Lieb and Robinson solving for $\mathbf{G}$ with a Fourier transform.